# Does a child class object's memory release in tkinter after you're "done" with it?

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, memory

I know that generally garbage collection releases memory after there are no more references to a variable.  So basically if I were to run a script that initiates a class object then once the object is done being used the allocated memory will be released.  But what if that class object is called from a tkinter loop?  If I use the object to do something is the memory allocation retained even after the action is completed?

On top of that, if I was to have a tkinter UI that had a top level parent class that could potentially call a bunch of different functions which each used/initiated the same child class, would I end up with alot of child objects hanging out taking up space for the duration of the parent object even though there are no explicit references to the child object outside of the function it's initiated in?  (I apologize if my terminology is off I'm very new to OOP!)

My gut tells me that there's just one instance of the child created, and though it is retained for the duration of the tkinter loop/parent object, the same child object gets used for everything being called under the umbrella of the parent object instead of any new ones being created ...But I'm not sure exactly.

Ex.

```
class ui_main:
    def __init__(self):
 
        self.root = tk.Tk()  

        bttnA = tk.Button(self.root, text='Get data for A', command=self.get_dataset_a)
        bttnB = tk.Button(self.root, text='Get data for B', command=self.get_dataset_b)
        bttnC = tk.Button(self.root, text='Get data for C', command=self.get_dataset_c)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_dataset_a(self):
        starttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        # (do stuff...)
        endtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        
        stats = stats_tracking()
        stats.sendtotable(starttime, endtime)

    def get_dataset_b(self):
        starttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        # (do stuff...)
        endtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        stats = stats_tracking()
        stats.sendtotable(starttime, endtime)

    def get_dataset_c(self):
        starttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        # (do stuff...)
        endtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        
        stats = stats_tracking()
        stats.sendtotable(starttime, endtime)

class stats_tracking():
    def __init__(self):

    def sendtotable(self, starttime, endtime):

        # (store stats in a table to be used in calculations later)

#################################################################################
# start/open the ui 
def open_the_app():     
    ToolBox = ui_main()

open_the_app()
```

There wouldn't be any references to stats_tracking() in the top level ui_main(), so references would be isolated to the function it's being used in.

The stats_tracking() class would be much more robust than just sending things to a table and would be used in a couple other UIs/parent classes.  I'd ideally like to use it in many if not most of the functions under each of my various UI classes, however if every function it's used in creates a new object that's retained in memory for the duration of that instance of the tkinter loop I feel like that could use up alot of memory real quick.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code isn't runnable as posted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.